Cart in Django is not updating in frontend but working fine in database
I'm making an ecom site. When customer select Product size from dropdown boxes, it sends the correct selected size in backend but showing default value in frontend.
My HTML code for this:
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="size-cart{{ product.id }}">
{% for key, value in sizes.items %}
{% if key == product.id %}
  <option selected value="{{ value.id }}">{{ value.size }}</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for size in all_sizes %}
  <option value="{{ size.id }}">{{ size.size }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

Frontend related code:
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.update-cart', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var product_id = $(this).data('index');
  var product_size = $('#size-cart'+ product_id).val();

  console.log("Size: ", product_size);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : "{% url 'cart_update' %}",
    data: {
      product_id : $(this).data('index'),
      product_qty: $('#select' + product_id + ' option:selected').text(),
      product_size: product_size,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'post'
    },
    success: function(json) {
      location.reload();
    },

    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){

    }
  });
})
</script>

Related code in views.py file
def cart_update(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        print("request POST data:", request.POST)
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        product_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))
        size_id = int(request.POST.get('product_size'))
        selected_size = get_object_or_404(Product_Size, id=size_id)
        print("Selected size: ", selected_size)

        

        cart.update(product=product_id, quantity = product_qty, size=selected_size)

        response = JsonResponse({'qty': product_qty})
        messages.success(request, ("Your cart has been updated...."))
        
        return response

Related code in cart.py in Cart class:
   def update(self, product, quantity, size):
        prdct = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product)
        #print(f"Found product: {prdct}")

        product_id = str(prdct.id)
        product_qty = int(quantity)

        print("Size passed in cart.update ", size)

    
        

        if product_id in self.cart:

            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = product_qty
            if size:
                self.cart[product_id]['size']= size.size
                print(f"Updated cart: {self.cart[product_id]['size']}")
            else:
                self.cart[product_id]['size']= None

            self.session['cart'] = self.cart
            self.session.modified = True
            print("session updated: ", self.session.get('cart'))

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:

            current_user = Profile.objects.filter(user__id=self.request.user.id)
            carty = str(self.cart)
            carty = carty.replace("\'", "\"")
            current_user.update(old_cart=str(carty))

        return self.cart

In the print() in cart.update() I'm getting the correct info like which dropdown I selected. And also in Ajax, selected size is passed correctly.

I selected xxl size

After clicking update button it remains M-32 again. It works perfectly for quantity. How to solve this?

Since you're returning JSON in the response you're probably using AJAX to make this request? How is the frontend handling the update to the UI then? Please show the code for the frontend that makes this request and handles updates to the UI.

sorry for that, I uploaded that code

It seems like you're just reloading the page, please show the view and other related code for this page. Just a guess though, you're looping over sizes: for key, value in sizes.items but then comparing with the products id: if key == product.id This might be the reason for the incorrect size, although if that's just bad naming where product is actually meant to be the product size then I might be wrong.

I rendered product in views.py file, I also uploaded that file

The only difference I see is selected in the options for sizes which means it applies selected to all options, which should be conditional.

Can you please share what to do?

Try the following:
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="size-cart{{ product.id }}">
{% for key, value in sizes.items %}
{% if key == product.id %}
  <option selected value="{{ value.id }}">{{ value.size }}</option>
{% else %}
  <option value="{{ value.id }}">{{ value.size }}</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for size in all_sizes %}
  <option value="{{ size.id }}">{{ size.size }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

Not sure, but it looks like you are asking the HTML to have only the correct product.id to be selected, but that conditional is bypassed if it doesn't match.  But what then?

This code is working correct.
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="size-cart{{ product.id }}">
{% for key, value in sizes.items %}
{% if key == product.id|slugify %}
  <option selected>{{ value }}</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for size in all_sizes %}
<option value="{{size.id}}">{{ size.size }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

